# Over voltage and backflow protection

Tags: low-power, over-voltage-protection, power-management

I'm drawing up a MCU based device for my bike to control light etc. The power comes from the dynamo, and at higher speeds it will produce a lot more voltage than the circuit can handle, so protection is needed. Also I like the +8V side to not discharge more than necessary. Attached picture is my take on this. A TL431 to shut off the bottom FET when secondary side > 8V, and a comparator switches top FET off when +8V is higher than VCC.

[image: Schematic]

Is it a sound circuit?

UPDATE:
I took Russells circuit from below and connected the comparator straight to the power from dynamo. No need to regulate something that isn't there :)

[image: Revised circuit]

Comment: As shown top FET body diode will conduct when FET is off. You can probably tolerate a Schottky or even silicone diode there. || TL431 appears to have a split personality :-). Its reference divider has GND0 as it's negative terminal **BUT** it's Anode is connected to GND1. "There will be problems". || At 8V out a Schottky diode loses about 5% of the energy which is probably not important. || If doing as you want it will either provide up to 8V or nothing. This is OK if say 6V is OK and 6-8V is in usual voltage range. If dynamo usually sits above 8V then you usually get no power.

Comment: Which approach is best depends on dynamo spec with speed. Telling us more about that will help us give you good answers.

Comment: Yes I know bout the top FET, I guess I can add one more Schottky than the ones in the rectifier.

Comment: Hehe, that 431 have really bugged me, the split personality. A optocouper would work I guess, but at a cost in mA.

Comment: About the dynamo, Shimano states 6V 2.4W. But it will go a lot higher than that, with no load of course. Even with load: I once had a Zener protecting a Supercap (that's one of the things that needs protection, and that Zener melted solder and plastic... and the cap was gonski.

Comment: There are two things you might be looking to do with your circuit: one is to limit the maximum voltage from the dynamo, the other is the control the charge state of a battery.  It would be good to understand a bit more about the battery part to provide the best guidance, not least because battery charging normally requires a higher voltage than the nominal battery voltage.

Comment: I think it will be ok, but I'll certainly monitor it, since the voltage can climb high with just a DMM connected. About the battery: Should have included it in the circuit, I'll be using a 8V4 90F supercap, so the battery managment will be easy. :)

Comment: A switched resistor load may be viable 10W aircooled ceramics are chap and available and relatively compact. Run at no more than 1/2 rated wattage. A PWM load controller that increased effective load with voltage would be useful. || Supercap from say 8V to 4V is about 2000 joule. Adequate for task. Usually :-).

Comment: @colintd & Russell
How about this: The voltage divider could be done with 3 resistors, first tap to the comparator, and second to a 431 that switches a FET, between Vcc and GND.

Comment: That's a not insignificant number of transistors and IC's to produce 3.3 V. How about just a 3.3 V regulator which can take your entire input range as-is?

Comment: @winny  good idea. It depends on whether you want every bit of energy at lower voltage level - but a good LDO has about the same dropout as a Schottky diode (my D1) so your suggestion works when Vin > Vmax. Regulator dissipation needs to be considered.  An issue is that he wants a Vmax limiter but it must pass lower voltages with minimal drop. Some regulators will do this, while others do strange things when Vin is below (Vreg+ Vdropout)

Comment: @winny
8V for lights on the bike, and 3V3 to a MCU that read sensors, pwm the mosfets for the lights. Let me qoute a guy from Discovery: "Why put a jet engine on a motorcycle? Because we CAN!"

Comment: How about an 8 V regulator followed by a 3.3 V one? The former would need to take the entire input voltage range. Probably hundreds of commercial offerings available for it.

Comment: @winny LDO must pass current when in dropout. Could have a bypass switch. Starts to sound familiar :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I’m thinking buck for both.

Comment: @Winny Buck-Boost - can't go wrong :-)

Comment: @MiNeMe The LM393 is open drain output. You'll need a pullup from output to positive rail to ensure the FET turns off.

Comment: @Russell It's there, but it's not visible :) Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptual only.
Minor "real world" detailing needed.
eg if an LM393 is used a pullup is essential from Q1 gate to V_alternator_dc.

PFET with Source to rectified Alternator output.

- When Vbat > Valternator_DC CMP1 output is high.
  PFET Q1 is off
- When VBat < Valternator_DC CMP1 output is low.
  PFET Q1 is on

Should work :-)

D2 & D3 power comparator from highest of Vbat or Valternator_DC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6IHV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Added:

"Just maybe". Catalysed by others talking about using a regulator.

Added regulator to allow operation above 8V in.
Allows regulator that is badly behaved in dropout.
Regulator must tolerate Vbat on it's output

A very well behaved regulator with suitable heatsink would allow a regulator only solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw55Oe.png)</sup>

Comment: That's a interesting suggestion. Vref could be taken from the 3V3, with a Zener as backup.

Answer (score 1):

An adjustable LDO regulator, followed by a Schottky diode (on the battery side of the LDO) is probably your easiest solution for dealing with the variable voltage from the dynamo/alternative.

You get minimal voltage/power drop, configurable voltage limit (via feedback resistors), self-discharge protection, and all with well proven cheap components.

Comment: On the contrary, I am. Not in the pictures, but there are 2 zeners in parallell with the super cap, should something go wrong. Thanks for your replies, I've never thought of a primary LDO, that's a much more light solution.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the comments.  I will tweak the answer. I was particularly thinking about a LiPo battery pack which will need more charge control than just voltage.  However, an LDO + diode might still be the best solution for primary protection against overvoltage from the dynamo.